# Microcontroller Always ON domain

Tags: microcontroller

I have a question about the [MPC5606S Microcontroller](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MPC5606S.pdf).
I have very minimal software knowledge and only want to understand in hardware perspective.

On page 68 of the MCU datasheet, we have a block diagram which mentioned PD0 Always ON domain.

But in this [Reference Manual](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/MPC5606SRM.pdf) of the MCU, on page 1235, the block diagram mentions that this Always ON domain have wakeup input pads.

- What are the ports/pins of the MCU in the Always ON Domain?
  (Are the Always ON domain pins the same as mentioned in Table 41-1 on page 1238?)
- Can't we have any output ports in the Always ON domain?
- Is it necessary that I have to connect it in one of the pins in PD0 Domains if I want to drive a PWM output during Mircocontroller sleep condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Always on domain: Power is present.
- Wake-up pads: Wake the MCU from sleep mode.

---

The reference on the first datasheet, always on domain, means the electronic is always powered. You cannot selectively power-off this section.

The wakeup pads are for waking up the device from sleep mode (MCU).

Sleep mode and power are two different things. Power means you physically have a voltage present, while sleep is that the CPU, Memory, and others while being powered, doesn't do anything to save power.

---

PWM During sleep mode will really depend on which MCU you are using. You need to find MCU which contains a hardware PWM module that can operate during sleep. Some MCU has this functionality like the PIC family from Microchip.

Another way to generate a PWM during sleep is to use a GPIO and a timer, set the timer so that the device wakes up each time the pin state has to be changed, this will likely be less efficient than the solution above.

Comment: Thank you. Before I accept the answer, could you edit your answer to provide answer to my third question.I want to drive a PWM Output during sleep condition. Can I do that by using any GPIO port with the help of software or should I just use the PD0 Domain

Comment: @Newbie edited the answer.